# Member function pointer cast, from Derived to Base class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm doing the following:

- Taking a member function pointer with **3 params** from a **derived class**.
- Casting it to a member function pointer from **the base class** with **0 params**.
- Casting it to **the base class** with **the 3 params** back.
- Calling it.

It works fine (so far), but should i keep it?

Description of current code:

EventsWarehouse is used to store and invoke events:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

class EventsWarehouse
{
public:
    typedef std::tuple<AView*, void (AView::*)()>           box_t;
    typedef std::unordered_multimap<std::string, box_t>     boxes_t;

    void        storeEvent(std::string const &event, AView *v, void (AView::*callback)())
        {
            this->_events.insert(std::make_pair(event, std::make_tuple(v, callback)));
            return ;
        }

    template<typename... Args>
    bool        fireEvent(std::string const &event, Args... args)
        {
            auto                it = this->_events.find(event);
            AView               *v;
            void                (AView::*callback_)();
            void                (AView::*callback)(Args...);

            for (; it != this->_events.end(); it++)
            {
                v = std::get<0>(it->second);
                callback_ = std::get<1>(it->second);
                /*
                ** CAST #2
                ** <void (AView::*)()>
                **  to
                ** <void (AView::*)(std::string, int, double)>
                **  before call
                */
                callback = reinterpret_cast<void (AView::*)(Args...)>(callback_);
                (v->*callback)(args...);
            }
            return (true);
        }
private:
    boxes_t         _events;

};
```

View classes stored in the above class:

```
class AView
{
protected:
    AView(){}
};

class DerivedView : public AView
{
public:
    void    fooCallback(std::string s, int i, double d)
        {
            std::cout << "DerivedView::fooCallback received " << s << ", " << i << ", " << d << std::endl;
            return ;
        }
};
```

Main:

```
int                         main(void)
    {
        DerivedView     dv;
        EventsWarehouse ewh;

        /*
        ** CAST #1
        ** <void (DerivedView::*)(std::string, int, double)>
        **  to
        ** <void (AView::*)()>
        **  for storing purpose
        */
        ewh.storeEvent("event 1", &dv, reinterpret_cast<void (AView::*)()>(&DerivedView::fooCallback));
        ewh.fireEvent("event 1", std::string("Hello World"), 42, 84.42);
        return (0);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @rozina I think the implied question is "It seems to be working, but is what I have described an okay thing to do, or could it potentially cause a problem?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to draft n4296 for C++11 specification, 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast] §10

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to member of Y of type T2” if T1 and T2 are both function types or both object types.72 The
>   null member pointer value (4.11) is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type. The result of this conversion is unspecified, except in the following cases:
>
> — converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a different pointer to member function
>   type and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.
>
> — converting a prvalue of type “pointer to data member of X of type T1” to the type “pointer to data
>   member of Y of type T2” (where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1)
>   and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.
>   the conversion to a pointer to member function with no parameters and back to a member functions with correct parameters should give back original pointer.

IMHO, the problem is that `fooCallback` is only defined on `DerivedView` class, and as such it is **not** a member function of class `AView`.

This would be correct:

```
void (AView::*p)() = reinterpret_cast<void (AView::*)()>(&DerivedView::fooCallback);
void (DerivedView::*callback)(std::string, int, double) =
       reinterpret_cast<void (DerivedView::*)(std::string, int, double)>(p);
v->callback("Hello World"), 42, 84.42);
```

provided `v` is a `AView *` pointing to a `DerivedView`

But as you end converting a `void (DerivedView::*)(std::string, int, double)` to a `void (AView::*)(std::string, int, double)` they are different type so conversion is unspecified

It works, because common implementation for non static non virtual member functions is simply a normal (non member) function with a hidden parameter being `this`. So the pointer to member just stores the address of that function and correctly calls it with a pointer to a `DerivedView` giving expected result. But a different implementation could also store the actual type and raise an exception (or do anything else).

TL/DR: As you end with a conversion from `void (DerivedView::*)(std::string, int, double)` to `void (AView::*)(std::string, int, double)` you do not cast to pointer to member to its original type and invoke undefined behaviour.